# Weights of Seq2Seq Models

Tags: tensorflow, sequence

I went through the code and I'm afraid I don't grasp an important point.

I can't seem to find the weights matrix of the model for the encoder and decoder, neither where they are updated. I found the target_weights but it seems to be reinitialized at every `get_batch()` call so I don't really understand what they stand for either.

My actual goal is to concatenate two hidden states of two source encoders for one decoder by applying a linear transformation with a weight matrix that I'll have to train along with the model (I'm building a manytoone model), but I have no idea where to start because of my problem mentionned above.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you start. There are a couple of models implemented in [tensorflow.python.ops.seq2seq.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py) (with/without buckets, attention, etc.) but take a look at the definition for `embedding_attention_seq2seq` (which is the one called in their example model [seq2seq_model.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/seq2seq.py) that you seem to be referencing):

```
def embedding_attention_seq2seq(encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs, cell,
                                num_encoder_symbols, num_decoder_symbols,
                                num_heads=1, output_projection=None,
                                feed_previous=False, dtype=dtypes.float32,
                                scope=None, initial_state_attention=False):

  with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope or "embedding_attention_seq2seq"):
    # Encoder.
    encoder_cell = rnn_cell.EmbeddingWrapper(cell, num_encoder_symbols)
    encoder_outputs, encoder_state = rnn.rnn(
        encoder_cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype)

    # First calculate a concatenation of encoder outputs to put attention on.
    top_states = [array_ops.reshape(e, [-1, 1, cell.output_size])
                  for e in encoder_outputs]
    attention_states = array_ops.concat(1, top_states)
    ....
```

You can see where it picks out the top layer of encoder outputs as `top_states` before handing them off to the decoder.

So you could implement a similar function with two encoders and concatenate those states before handing off to the decoder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is exactly what im currently doing :-) But my questions was more about the weights management which is still a bit confusing to me. I guess i'll just have to test and see. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

The value created in the get_batch function is only used for the first iteration. Even though the weights are passed every time into the function, their value gets updated as a global variable in the Seq2Seq model class in the init function.

```py
    with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
        # Gradients and SGD update operation for training the model.
        params = tf.trainable_variables()
        if not forward_only:
            self.gradient_norms = []
            self.updates = []
            opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
            for b in range(len(buckets)):
                gradients = tf.gradients(self.losses[b], params)
                clipped_gradients, norm = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients,
                                                                 max_gradient_norm)
                self.gradient_norms.append(norm)
                self.updates.append(opt.apply_gradients(
                    zip(clipped_gradients, params), global_step=self.global_step))

    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
```

The weights are fed seperately as a place-holder because they are normalized in the get_batch function to create zero weights for the PAD inputs.

```py
    # Batch decoder inputs are re-indexed decoder_inputs, we create weights.
    for length_idx in range(decoder_size):
        batch_decoder_inputs.append(
            np.array([decoder_inputs[batch_idx][length_idx]
                      for batch_idx in range(self.batch_size)], dtype=np.int32))

        # Create target_weights to be 0 for targets that are padding.
        batch_weight = np.ones(self.batch_size, dtype=np.float32)
        for batch_idx in range(self.batch_size):
            # We set weight to 0 if the corresponding target is a PAD symbol.
            # The corresponding target is decoder_input shifted by 1 forward.
            if length_idx < decoder_size - 1:
                target = decoder_inputs[batch_idx][length_idx + 1]
            if length_idx == decoder_size - 1 or target == data_utils.PAD_ID:
                batch_weight[batch_idx] = 0.0
        batch_weights.append(batch_weight)
```